# How to return SOAP responses to my HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services, soap

Im doing a website in HTML, and need to create a table with SOAP WEBSERVICE responses.

I'm trying a lot of methods, but nothing work

How code i use to do that?

This is my HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Recibos de Frete</title>
    
    
    
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    
    
    
  </head>

  <body>

    <html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Table Style</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; width=device-width;">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://ws.cargolift.com.br:12510/ws/WEB013AP.apw",true);
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {

                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

                      // http://www.terracoder.com convert XML to JSON 
                      var json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(xmlhttp.responseXML);
                      var result = json.Body[0].GetQuoteResponse[0].GetQuoteResult[0].Text;
                      // Result text is escaped XML string, convert string to XML object then convert to JSON object
                      json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(XMLObjectifier.textToXML(result));
                      alert(symbol + ' Stock Quote: $' + json.Stock[0].Last[0].Text); 
                     }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://ws.cargolift.com.br/portalcarreteiro.apw/LISTACONTRATO");
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
                     '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:por="http://ws.cargolift.com.br/portalcarreteiro.apw">'+
                        '<soapenv:Header/>'+
                        '<soapenv:Body>'+
                            '<por:LISTACONTRATO>'+
                              '<por:ORECCONTRATO>'+
                                  '<por:BRANCH></por:BRANCH>'+
                                  '<por:CGC>84061359991</por:CGC>'+
                                  '<por:CONTRATO></por:CONTRATO>'+
                                  '<por:DATAFIM>2016-09-23</por:DATAFIM>'+
                                  '<por:DATAINI>2016-09-18</por:DATAINI>'+
                                  '<por:TIPODATA>EmissÃ£o</por:TIPODATA>'+
                              '</por:ORECCONTRATO>'+
                            '</por:LISTACONTRATO>'+
                        '</soapenv:Body>'+
                      '</soapenv:Envelope>';
                    xmlhttp.send(xml);

                    var xmlResponse =xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;

                    var fullNodeList = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("NMFILIAL");

</script>

<body>
<div class="table-title">
<h3>Recibos de Frete</h3>
</div>
<table class="table-fill">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="text-left">Filial</th>
<th class="text-left">Numero Recibo</th>
<th class="text-left">Valor Adiantamento</th>
<th class="text-left">Valor Saldo</th>
<th class="text-left">Valor Frete</th>
<th class="text-left">Vencimento</th>
<th class="text-left">Status</th>
<th class="text-left">Pagamento Adiantamento</th>
<th class="text-left">Pagamento Saldo Frete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="table-hover">
<tr>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
<td class="text-left"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  

  </body>
    
    
    
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my SOAP RESPONSE:

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <LISTACONTRATORESPONSE xmlns="http://ws.cargolift.com.br/portalcarreteiro.apw">
         <LISTACONTRATORESULT>
            <DADOSCONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000411035</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-22</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>03</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>PARANAGUA</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>221.73000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>LIBERADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>3</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>234.39000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000411052</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-22</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>03</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>PARANAGUA</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>221.73000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>BLOQUEADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>2</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>234.39000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000411062</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-22</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>03</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>PARANAGUA</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>221.73000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>LIBERADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>3</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>234.39000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000411073</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-22</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>03</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>PARANAGUA</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>221.73000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>LIBERADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>3</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>234.39000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000411212</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-22</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>01</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>CURITIBA MATRIZ</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>44.35000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>LIBERADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>3</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>46.87000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000411252</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-22</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>03</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>PARANAGUA</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>221.73000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>LIBERADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>3</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>234.39000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000411809</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-23</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>03</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>PARANAGUA</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>195.70000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>BLOQUEADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>2</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>206.87000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000411675</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-24</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>08</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>SAO JOSE DOS PINHAIS</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>240.66000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>BLOQUEADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>2</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>244.42000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000412185</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-26</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>08</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>SAO JOSE DOS PINHAIS</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>123.85000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>BLOQUEADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>2</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>125.78000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000412568</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-27</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>08</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>SAO JOSE DOS PINHAIS</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>321.85000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>BLOQUEADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>2</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>337.01000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000412629</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-27</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>03</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>PARANAGUA</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>221.73000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>BLOQUEADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>2</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>234.39000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
               <LISTACONTRATO>
                  <ADIANTAMENTO>0.00000000</ADIANTAMENTO>
                  <CONTRATO>000412663</CONTRATO>
                  <DATAVENCTO>2016-09-27</DATAVENCTO>
                  <FILIALORI>03</FILIALORI>
                  <NMFILIAL>PARANAGUA</NMFILIAL>
                  <SALDO>221.73000000</SALDO>
                  <SITUACAO>BLOQUEADO</SITUACAO>
                  <STATUS>2</STATUS>
                  <VLRFRETE>234.39000000</VLRFRETE>
               </LISTACONTRATO>
            </DADOSCONTRATO>
         </LISTACONTRATORESULT>
      </LISTACONTRATORESPONSE>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What i do to put soap responses line into html table lines?